# How to input string tokens into a 2d array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

Trying to get a list of inputs with delimiter "|":

> Public|Jane|Q|Ms.|600|Maple Street|Your Town|Iowa|12345

And then would like to input them into a 2d array (customerData) that I can manipulate.

I realize I'm missing int main() and code for reading file/input. Just including the relevant code. I can get the input, its the putting into customerData getting out of that I'm struggling with.

```
#define INPUT_LENGTH 128
#define FIELD_LENGTH 30
#define NUM_FIELDS   9


char input[INPUT_LENGTH];                    
char customerData[NUM_FIELDS][FIELD_LENGTH];  
int  element = 0;
int customer = 0;

while ( fgets( input, INPUT_LENGTH, data ) != NULL ) {
  char* token = strtok(input, "|"); // start tokeninzing
  while (token) { // end of string last token is NULL
    strcpy(customerData[customer][element], token); 
    token = strtok(NULL, "|"); 
    element++;
  }
  customer++;  
}

for (int i = 0; i < entry; i++) {
  for (int k = 0; k < element; k++) {
    printf("%s\n", customerData[i][k]);
  }
}
```

I'm expecting output like this:

```
Public
Jane
Q
Ms.
600
Maple Street
Your Town
Iowa
12345
```

Comment: What output/errors are you currently getting?

Comment: What is `data`? What output are you getting? What is `entry`?

Comment: on stackoverflow, the expectation is the posting of a [mcve] not just some code snippets.

Comment: Tip: remove the _potential_ `'\n'` from `input` with `input[strcspn(input,"\n")] = 0;` right after the `if (fgets() ....` or add it to the token list `"|\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

the posted code keeps adding 1 to `element`, even when it is a new line/new customer.

Suggest, after the statement:

```
customer++;
```

to insert the statement:

```
element = 0;
```

also regarding:

```
char customerData[NUM_FIELDS][FIELD_LENGTH];
```

I would expect the first part of the array to be a customer number, then NUM_FIELDS and then FIELD_LENGTH

Also, for clarity suggest `element` be replaced with `fieldNum`